# JUnit, Spring Context and Webflow

Tags: junit, spring-webflow

I'm trying to configure JUnit to work with Spring, but I cannot.
My problem is that it doesn't find the webflow files, so it fails the execution.
However, this sounds strange to me, because I'm not actually testing webflow stuff! I want to start from the controller to the database.
So, this is what I'm doing

I create a test class this way:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:/web-application-config.xml"})
public class MyControllerToTest {
        @Autowired
    private MyController ctr;

    @Test
    ....
}
```

In classpath, I inserted src/main/resources, where the web-application-config.xml is located. Here its content:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

<!-- Scans for application @Components to deploy -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.infoone.mycontrollerpackage"/>

<!-- Imports the configurations of the different infrastructure systems of the application -->
<import resource="webflow-config.xml" />
<import resource="webmvc-config.xml" />
<import resource="data-access-config.xml" />
<import resource="repository-config.xml" />
<import resource="security-config.xml" />
```

When I run as JUnit the MyControllerToTest class, I get the following:

```
ERROR: org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener
[org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@6419fa] to prepare test instance [com.infoone.myapp.MyControllerToTest@10036f2]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flowExecutor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'flowRegistry' while setting bean property 'flowDefinitionLocator'; nested exception is         org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flowRegistry': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: An I/O Exception occurred resolving the flow location pattern '/**/*-flow.xml'
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flowRegistry': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: An I/O Exception occurred resolving the flow location pattern '/**/*-flow.xml'
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: An I/O Exception occurred resolving the flow location pattern '/**/*-flow.xml'
...
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [WEB-INF/flows/] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist[/code]
```

Maybe, you also need my web-flow-config file, also located in src/main/resources (whereas my flows are in WEB-INF/flows/**/*.xml, but which I also tried to move to src/main/resources with the same results):

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:webflow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"
   xmlns:faces="http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config-2.3.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces/spring-faces-2.2.xsd">

<!-- Executes flows: the central entry point into the Spring Web Flow system -->
<webflow:flow-executor id="flowExecutor">
    <webflow:flow-execution-listeners>
        <webflow:listener ref="facesContextListener"/>
        <webflow:listener ref="securityFlowExecutionListener" />
        <webflow:listener ref="icefacesFlowListener" />
        <webflow:listener ref="myFlowListener" />
        <webflow:listener ref="myExceptionListener" />
    </webflow:flow-execution-listeners>
</webflow:flow-executor>

<!-- The registry of executable flow definitions -->
<webflow:flow-registry id="flowRegistry" flow-builder-services="facesFlowBuilderServices" base-path="/WEB-INF/flows">
    <webflow:flow-location-pattern value="/**/*-flow.xml" />
</webflow:flow-registry>

<!-- Configures the Spring Web Flow JSF integration -->
<faces:flow-builder-services id="facesFlowBuilderServices" development="true" />

<!-- Installs a listener that creates and releases the FacesContext for each request. -->
<bean id="facesContextListener" class="org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowFacesContextLifecycleListener"/>

<!-- Installs a listener to apply Spring Security authorities -->
<bean id="securityFlowExecutionListener" class="org.springframework.webflow.security.SecurityFlowExecutionListener" />

<bean id="icefacesFlowListener" class="com.icesoft.spring.security.WebflowListener" />

<bean id="myFlowListener" class="com.infoone.myapp.spring.webflow.AutowiringFlowExecutionListener" />

<bean id="myExceptionListener" class="com.infoone.myapp.exception.MyExceptionListener" />
```

Please consider that I'm also using JSF and Icefaces (which I don't want to test via JUnit at the moment).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your webflow files are probably in the webapp source rather than the Java source, which is why they cannot be found in your junit tests.

I suggest making your Spring configuration files more modular, then changing your tests to include only those Spring configuration required to run the tests.

Comment: Hi, thank you, but I'm not sure I got what you said about the modularity. How would you suggest to organize them? Hierarchically?

Comment: However, the path doesn't look like is the one for webapp, but the one from the root of the project.

Comment: Organize them by architectural layer. This way, if you want to perform integration tests from controllers to the database, you include the Spring config files for controllers, services (if you have them) and your data access layer. You don't need to include config files for your view layer.

Comment: but they are organized that way, I guess, but I need to create an ad-hoc application-context for every "type" of execution (operation, unit test, web layer test etc). Correct?